# How to manage requirements of a User Story

Tags: tfs, agile

I am working on a project using TFS2010 and the Agile process template. In TFS I have a collection of user stories, but I am wondering what is the best way to manage the requirements of the user story. For example, one user story will require a search page and a requirement would be that the "Search" button should be disabled until some "search text" is entered.

My original plan was to attach a bunch of "Task" items with the "Activity" field set to "Requirement" to the "User Story". I would then create some tasks that would outline the actual implementation and which will satisfy the Requirement tasks.

Would this be a sensible way to manage this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Task work items are for actual work being performed and taking time.

User Stories *are* the requirements.

What sort of "management" did you have in mind?

Comment: One of the "development" tasks I've identified is that a Search page is needed. Now one of the requirements of this page is that the "Search Button" is displayed until some text is entered in the "Search Text Box". So how would I track/manage the requirement that the Search page contains this functionality?

Comment: That should be a user story or part of a user story, perhaps in acceptance criteria.

Comment: Could acceptance criteria be managed as "items" within TFS or would they simply be described as part of the user story content?

Comment: I would keep them as part of the user story. Among other things, test cases would then be written (linked to the user story) to confirm that the acceptance criteria are met).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you construct a tree of Work Items with Parent/Child relations:

```
User Story: As a user I want a Search page 
  Child US #1: As a user I want to be able to enter latin & greek search terms
  Child US #2: As an admin I want to be notified for User-searches that yielded no results
  Child US #3: ...
```

You can assigned Story Points to each Child - node, needless to say that you can then assign Children to each Child.
At the point where you are satisfied with the details you have in your UserStories, you can start breaking them up into doable Tasks.
A nice tool to visualize Trees of work items can be found [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a35b6010-750b-47f6-a7a5-41f0fa7294d2).

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you call a requirement is what in scrum is generally referred to as a user story's **acceptance criteria**. If all you need is a sentence or two, I suggest you write them in the story's description. If you need a more elaborate setup is useful for you, you can use a linked child work item. You should consider using the **test case** work item type. This will give you the added benefit of grounding the story's "requirements" in actual tests with MTM.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider "importing" the "Requirement" type into the Agile template. TFS 2010 provides another template (I believe it's called CMMI or something of that sort) and it allows you to import the Requirement type. On my project, we just did that and are about to start using it to easily keep track of more formal requirements (i.e. the acceptance criteria). Makes it easy for reporting on larger projects.